# Coding in excel across sheets

Tags: excel, if-statement, spreadsheet

I am creating a Risk Catalog for a project. I have one sheet in Excel titled "Risk Log". In that sheet one column is labeled "Impact" (with the options to select Negligible, Marginal, Severe, Critical, or Catastrophic)  and another one is labeled "Probability" (with the options to select Very Unlikely, Unlikely, Possible, Likely, or Very Likely). I also have another sheet labeled "Risk Metrics" shown here:  [image]
The table to the left indicates the Priority order for all risks based on their Impact & Probability, and the table to the right is what I am trying to work with. As you can see, the tiny table on the bottom calculates how many risks are "Green, Yellow, and Red" based on the table. That code has already been set. However, I am having trouble populating the table to the right. What I would like to do, is for the table on the right to indicate how many risks fall into each category (AKA how many risk are "Severe & Likely" or any combination: For example if only 1 risk was both Severe AND Likely, that cell would say 1, and 2 if two risks were that combination) I would like to use an IF AND  statement that would cover all the risks that are in my Risk Log (could be up to 100)

Thank you very much!!

Here in an example of what the Risk Log might look like when completed.

[image: Risk log]

Comment: use an array formula (ctrl+enter), like this: =COUNT(IF((Impact="Negligible")*(Probability="Possible"),Impact))  (which it will then write with {} around the formula

Comment: @AlexT82 Hi Alex, Thank you very much, I semi-understand what you are doing. I have inserted this into the box where Severe & Possible match up  = COUNT(IF(('Risk Log'!Impact="Severe")*('Risk Log'!Probability="Possible"), Impact)) However, although I am not getting any errors, the number stays at zero (even though I have two instances of this occurring  in my Risk log. Do you by any chance see where I could have made an error ? Thanks!

Comment: switch COUNT to SUM, and then add a 1 in the true area, and a 0 in the false area.
= SUM(IF(('Risk Log'!Impact="Severe")*('Risk Log'!Probability="Possible"), 1,0))

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If I understand your quesiton correctly, you are trying to count how many `Impact x Probability` combination in the table `5x5 Risk Count` but let me know if this is what you intended to do.

The formula you can use from `cell N5` is:

```
=COUNTIFS('Risk Log'!$E$2:$E$12,N$10,'Risk Log'!$F$2:$F$12,$M5)
```

You can drag it over to the right and down to cover all the fields.  Try and let me know.